# Class inheritance selector in SASS / jQuery?

Tags: jquery, sass

I extend a class with `@extend` :

```
.a {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}

.b {
  @extend .a;
  color: blue;
}

.c {
  /* empty class */
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>test A</div>
<div class='b'>test B</div>
<div class='c'>test C</div>
```

Now I would like a jQuery selector that returns the first 2 divs.

I know I can do :

```
$('.a,.b')
```

But is there any way I could do something like 'give me everything that is class `a` or extended from class `a` ?

Comment: `$('.a').slice(0,2).css('color','red')` [jQuery Slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) lets you select the divs you want

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I could do something like 'give me everything that is class a or extended from class a?

Unfortunately not as JavaScript only has knowledge of what's in the DOM, not what what was in the pre-processed SASS. The closest you could get to this is to use multiple selectors.